# Imported model animation differs from what I see in Blender

Tags: animation, three.js

So I made a very simple object and animation in Blender. Just bones rotation. Nothing more.

[image]

And here what I see in Three.JS. Animation is smooth, it looks like what I have made in Blender, but it is not the same animation. It is more rough and not properly skinned.

[image]

No scaling, no extra processing. Just load model and add it to the scene.
Here are bits of my code:

```
  let loader = new THREE.JSONLoader()
  loader.load('/static/example.json', (geometry) => {
    let material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x1ca8b5 })
    material.skinning = true
    let mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, material)
  })
  ...
  playAnimation(name) {
    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(this._mesh)
    let action = mixer.clipAction(name)
    action.play()
    ...
    update in render loop
  }
```

Any clues what I made wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to increase Influences parameter in exporter.

[image]